# R: dplyr and row_number() does not enumerate as expected

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I want to enumerate each record of a dataframe/tibble resulted from a grouping. The index is according a defined order. If I use row_number() it does enumerate but within group. But I want that it enumerates without considering the former grouping.

Here is an example. To make it simple I used the most minimal dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

df0 <- data.frame( x1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=2)
                 , x2 = rep(letters[1:2], 2)
                 , y = floor(abs(rnorm(4)*10))
)
df0
#   x1 x2  y
# 1  A  a 12
# 2  A  b 24
# 3  B  a  0
# 4  B  b 12
```

Now, I group this table:

```
 df1 <- df0 %>% group_by(x1,x2) %>% summarize(y=sum(y))
```

This gives me a object of class tibble:

```
 # A tibble: 4 x 3
 # Groups:   x1 [?]
 #   x1    x2        y
 #   <fct> <fct> <dbl>
 # 1 A     a        12
 # 2 A     b        24
 # 3 B     a         0
 # 4 B     b        12
```

I want to add a row number to this table using row_numer():

```
 df2 <- df1 %>% arrange(desc(y)) %>% mutate(index = row_number())
 df2
 # A tibble: 4 x 4
 # Groups:   x1 [2]
 #   x1    x2        y index
 #   <fct> <fct> <dbl> <int>
 # 1 A     b        24     1
 # 2 A     a        12     2
 # 3 B     b        12     1
 # 4 B     a         0     2
```

row_number() does enumerate within the former grouping. This was not my intention. This can be avoid converting tibble to a dataframe first:

```
 df2 <- df2 %>% as.data.frame() %>% arrange(desc(y)) %>% mutate(index = row_number())
 df2
 #   x1 x2  y index
 # 1  A  b 24     1
 # 2  A  a 12     2
 # 3  B  b 12     3
 # 4  B  a  0     4
```

My question is: is this behaviour intended?
If yes: is it not very dangerous to incorporate former data processing into tibble? Which type of processing is incorporated?
At the moment I will convert tibble into dataframe to avoid this kind of unexpected results.

Comment: What about adding `ungroup() %>%`  before `mutate(index = row_number())`?

Comment: yes, the behavior is intended since you still have grouping of previous case on. You need to `ungroup()` first. Try `df1 %>% ungroup() %>% arrange(desc(y)) %>% mutate(index = row_number())` Or do `df1 <- df0 %>% group_by(x1,x2) %>% summarize(y=sum(y)) %>% ungroup()`.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it dangerous to retain grouping--I often have multiple steps to do in a workflow that all build upon the same grouping. It's more a matter of knowing that that's what will happen and acting accordingly, i.e. calling `ungroup` when you don't want groups anymore

Comment: You can save a line of code by replacing `ungroup()` by using `summarize(.groups = "drop")` which returns an `ungroup`ed `tibble`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment: yes, retaining grouping is intended, and in many cases useful. It's only dangerous if you don't understand how `group_by` works—and that's true of any function. To undo `group_by`, you call `ungroup`.

Take a look at the [`group_by` docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html), as they're very thorough and explain how this function interacts with others, how grouping is layered, etc. The docs also explain how each call to `summarise` removes a layer of grouping—it might be there that you got confused about what's going on.

For example, you can group by `x1` and `x2`, summarize `y`, and create a row number, which will give you the rows according to `x1` (`summarise` removed a layer of grouping, i.e. drops the `x2` grouping). Then ungrouping allows you to get row numbers based on the entire data frame.

```r
library(dplyr)

df0 %>%
  group_by(x1, x2) %>%
  summarise(y = sum(y)) %>%
  mutate(group_row = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(all_df_row = row_number())
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   x1    x2        y group_row all_df_row
#>   <fct> <fct> <dbl>     <int>      <int>
#> 1 A     a        12         1          1
#> 2 A     b         2         2          2
#> 3 B     a        10         1          3
#> 4 B     b        23         2          4
```

A use case—I do this for work probably every day—is to get sums within multiple groups (again, `x1` and `x2`), then to find the shares of those values within their larger group (after peeling away a layer of grouping, this is `x1`) with `mutate`. Again, here I ungroup to show the shares instead of the entire data frame.

```r
df0 %>%
  group_by(x1, x2) %>%
  summarise(y = sum(y)) %>%
  mutate(share_in_group = y / sum(y)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(share_all_df = y / sum(y))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   x1    x2        y share_in_group share_all_df
#>   <fct> <fct> <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 A     a        12          0.857       0.255 
#> 2 A     b         2          0.143       0.0426
#> 3 B     a        10          0.303       0.213 
#> 4 B     b        23          0.697       0.489
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I have to delve into tidyverse.

Comment: Great explanation. I too had my brain wrecked by group and ungroup in the past.

Answer (score 2):

As camille nicely showed, there are good reasons for wanting to have the result of `summarize()` retain additional layers of grouping and it's a [documented](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) behaviour so not really dangerous or unexpected per se.

However one additional tip is that if you are just going to call `ungroup()` after `summarize()` you might as well use `summarize(.groups = "drop")` which will return an `ungroup`ed `tibble` and save you a line of code.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df0 <- data.frame(
  x1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 2),
  x2 = rep(letters[1:2], 2),
  y = floor(abs(rnorm(4) * 10))
)

df0 %>% 
  group_by(x1,x2) %>% 
  summarize(y=sum(y), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  arrange(desc(y)) %>% 
  mutate(index = row_number())
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   x1    x2        y index
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 A     b         8     1
#> 2 A     a         2     2
#> 3 B     a         2     3
#> 4 B     b         1     4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>